# Почему новая AndroidStudio 2.1 не всегда обновляет приложение при загрузке?

Tags: android-studio

Поставил не так давно себе студио 2.1 очень ее хвалят так как появилась возможность быстро `HotSpot` обновлять приложение без повторной его загрузки.

Но я вот решил узнать у все как у меня проблема или у меня в настройках что то. Студия в 20% случаях не хочет обновлять приложение. Допустим последняя ситуация такая я экспериментировал с `progressBar` и поставил его инициализацию в методе `onCreate` и поставил в активити обычную кнопку загрузил приложение первый раз и все отлично. Как только открывается экран активити сразу видим `progressBar` и кнопку.

Потом я убрал инициализацию из `onCreate` и поставил показ `progressBar` при нажатии на кнопку, обновляю приложение, срабатывает `HotSpot` буквально 5 секунд и открывается обновленное активити на котором я ожидаю увидеть пустой экран и кнопу на нем, но я вижу тоже самое... Инициализированый прогрес бар болтается на экране...

В таких случаях я сверху нажимаю на кнопку стоп и опять уже без `HotSpot` перезапускаю приложение и все нормально обновляется...

Но как тогда понять в каких случаях обновляется все нормально а в каких нет?? Ведь сейчас я работал с UI интерфейсом и все видно, а когда я работаю с передачей данных, то не понятно, обновился код или нет и это может вызывать заблуждение при исключеии ошибок...

Так как ты что то меняешь и рассчитываешь, что ошибка должна уйти, а она все равно есть, а все дело в том, что код не обновился...

Comment: В офф. презентации все это [подробно описано](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

Comment: @pavlofff Получается что удобство использования новой разработки ощутимо при верстке XML, но когда работаешь с кодом почти всегда нужно полностью перегружать приложение... Но в таком случае как по мне сомнительное преимущество, так как на старой версии студии приложение поднималось от 0 до вывода на экран +/- 30 сек, а здесь порядка 2-х минут и это в том случае если ты сразу загрузил его, а если сначала обновил Хот, потом понял, что нужно обновить полностью итого 3 минуты, что минимум в 6 раз дольше... В общем до конца не понятно преимущество